New dll in Dyalog APL
Is it possible to use a new dll in Dyalog APL? I can use the existing dll's just by setting ⎕USING, but this does not work if I download a new dll. Simply copying the dll in the directory and calling ⎕USING←'new_dll,new_dll.dll gives me the error:
Assembly load failed:
Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Program Files\Dyalog\Dyalog APL-64 19.0 Unicode\new_dll.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\new_dll.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

So I guess I must be missing some step. Has anyone done it?
More precisely, I want to use EPPLUS and IronXL in Dyalog APL.

I will use as an example the NuPkg Newtonsoft.Json as it is available under the MIT License.

I downloaded the package from nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json

Important step:  In Windows Explorer, I right clicked on the .nupkg file and chose Properties.  I ticked the Unblock button.

I used an unzip program to extract all the files inside the .nupkg package file.

In Dyalog, I verify that I can do some very basic operations with the Newtonsoft.Json namespace:


      ⎕using←'Newtonsoft.Json,D:\cust\tp5dec24\lib\net45\newtonsoft.json.dll'
      JsonConvert
(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert)
      JsonConvert.DefaultSettings
[Null]
      serializer←⎕NEW JsonSerializer
      serializer
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer
      ]assemblies
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089                 
bridge190-64_unicode, Version=19.0.50074.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb5ebc232de94dcf
System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089              
dyalognet, Version=19.0.50074.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb5ebc232de94dcf           
System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089                   
System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089     
System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a           
System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a     
System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089               
Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed         
System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089              

Regards,
Vince

Ticking the Unblock button is what was missing then. Thanks! :D
